# angular 2 error while displaying data from web Api

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Getting Issue while displaying data in client side getting from API
errors are as follows in a Link(please see the links for errors)

angular 2.0.0-beta.0
rxjs 5.0.0.beta

---

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKSQE.png)
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmQ9C.png)

```html
<div *ngFor="let model of models">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object" src="{{model.imageUrl}}" alt="..." style="width:40px; height:40px;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">{{model.question}}</h4>

                <p class="text-justify">
                    {{model.answer}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: Update angular 2 version  "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17", && "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",   "zone.js": "0.6.12",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an older version than `beta.17` than you need to use `#` instead of `let`

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wnLWAW?p=preview) reproduces the the same error. Changing `let` to `#` fixes it.

There is no need to import `FORM_DIRECTIVES` or add it to directives since quite some time.

Comment: angular 2.0.0-beta.0

Comment: thank you sir issue resolved by using # instead of let

Answer (score 0):

In beta / rc versions of Angular2, `NgFor` is a platform directive so there is nothing to include in your component to be able to use it. So it seems that you use an old version of Angular2 (alpha perhaps) where you needed to include it explicitly:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    (...)
  `,
  directives: [ NgFor ]
})
```